# How to have each UITableViewOption have its own data

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to have each choice in my UITableView to have its own unique set of data. For example, in my table view I have a list of states, then when I click on a state, I want each state to have a list of cities that correspond specifically to it. I have attached my code below, the code is strictly for the UITableView only.

I'm new to Xcode/Swift.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    let textCellIdentifier = "TextCell"
    
    var states = ["Illinois", "Indiana", "Kentucky", "Michigan", "Ohio", "Pennsylvania", "Wisconsin"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return states.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: textCellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        let row = indexPath.row
        cell.textLabel?.text = states[row]
        
        return cell
    }
    
    private func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)
        
        let row = indexPath.row
        print(states[row])
    }
```

Comment: in your didSelect `push` a new viewController.  Call it CityViewController. Then pass the state's cities as the dataSource for another tableview inside CityViewController

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, I will try to get it to work @Honey

Comment: I am new to swift and Xcode, do you think you could provide more information? It would be appreciated @Honey

Comment: Do I use a separate ViewController for each city and have a segue to perform the transition for each? I don't know how that will work considering I plan to have about 25 cities per state @Honey

Answer (score 0):

You can construct array model like this

```
struct MainItem {

   var name:String
   var cities:[String]

    init(name:String,cities:[String]) {

       self.name = name
       self.cities = cities
    }
}
```

//

```
let item1 = MainItem(name:"Illinois",cities:["city1","city2"])
let item2 = MainItem(name:"Indiana",cities:["city3","city4"])

var states = [item1,item2]
```

//

in `cellForRowAt`

```
cell.textLabel?.text = states[row].name
```

//

in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
let cities = states[row].cities
```

Comment: where do I add this to the code? And also, each city per state is going to have its own separate data. For example, I want to click on a state, then click on a city, an have more, unique data in each city. Is this code still applicable? @Sh_Khan

Comment: In any swift file outside of any class , as i did you have to make the city instead of an array of strings to array of **CityItem** struct and add the required properties for it depending on this example if you can't do it then it's your problem

Comment: Well your answer is wrong and doesn't work @Sh_Khan so maybe its your problem now

Answer (score 0):

I recently did this by creating separate classes for each of the delegates I wanted to have. Move all of the table functions into a new class and create an instance of the class in your new controller. In the view did load function set the delegate for the first table. Whenever you switch tables with a button or whatever, do nextTable.delegate = xxxx.

View controller code:

```
let eventLogTableController = EventLogTableController()
let missedEventLogController = MissedEventTableController()
@IBOutlet weak var emptyTableLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var missedEventLog: UITableView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {

    self.eventLog.delegate = eventLogTableController
```

Comment: thanks for the advice, I'm new to Xcode so I really don't know what that means. If you could provide more steps I'd appreciate if not, good day @Kevin Gardenhire

Comment: which part were you not sure about? I can add more code to try and clear it up

Comment: Moving all of table functions into a new class and creating an instance of it @Kevin Gardenhire